# Extract a string from all lines in a file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I want to extract a string which has a unique prefix from all lines in a file.
Though I am bad at string manipulations and regular expressions, I tried to use sed, cut commands but failed to extract the string.

My Sample file looks soemthing like

```
string1 string2 PREFIX_some_string1 string3 string4
string5 string6 PREFIX_some_string2 string7 string8
string9 string10 PREFIX_some_string3 string11 string12
string13 string14 PREFIX_some_string4 string15 string16
```

I just want to extract PREFIX_some_string as a whole as

```
PREFIX_some_string1
PREFIX_some_string2
PREFIX_some_string3
PREFIX_some_string4
```

What could be the command ?

Comment: Is the `PREFIX` at the same location on the line all the time?  If not edit your post and give a more correct example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep`:

```
$ grep -o 'PREFIX[^ ]*' file
PREFIX_some_string1
PREFIX_some_string2
PREFIX_some_string3
PREFIX_some_string4
```

This `grep`s for matches of `PREFIX` + whatever characters coming until a space is found. It just prints the match because we are using the `-o` option in `grep`: *Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line*.

Comment: Love "grep  -o" , but i would change command for " grep -oP 'PREFIX_[^\s]+' " to avoid non expected suffix.

Comment: Looks good. But can we delimit with any special character, not just space.

Comment: @Narain can you give some examples? It is best if you update your question with a full representative sample input.

Comment: Using -P flag to combine perl regex with grep could be the way to go. Best answer anyway

Answer (score 1):

Just a gawk command:

```
$ gawk 'match($0, "(PREFIX_[^[:blank:]]+)", a) {print a[1]}' file
```

Comment: PREFIX_String can be at any location.

Answer (score 1):

For the sample file, this will do:

```
awk '/PREFIX/' RS=" " file
PREFIX_some_string1
PREFIX_some_string2
PREFIX_some_string3
PREFIX_some_string4
```

This will pint the `PREFIX` section at any location on the line.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n 's/.* \(PREFIX_[^ ]*\).*/\1/p' YourFile
```

Assuming space char is the field/string separator and no other PREFIX_ are possible in structure

```
sed -n 's/\([^ ]\{1,\} \{1,\}\)\{2\}\(PREFIX_[^ ]*\).*/\1/p' YourFile
```

More accurate version to take only PREFIX_ as 3th field

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using **cut command**
**Cut:**
-d  delimiter as space
-f  column to be printed

```
$ cut -d " " -f3 sample.txt
```

PREFIX_some_string1
PREFIX_some_string2
PREFIX_some_string3
PREFIX_some_string4

Comment: Look at `OP`s comment in another answer. `PREFIX_String can be at any location. –  Narain`